# IE Object doesn't support this action - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables, cross-browser, reserved-words

I'm trying to draw a Google Map - works fine in FF, but in IE I get this error..

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action 
ct.js, line 135 character 5
```

Line 135 starts with `var mylatlongopt`

```
function initializeMap(latz, longz, co) { 
    var mylatlongopt = new google.maps.LatLng(latz, longz);
    var mapOptions = { center: mylatlongopt, zoom: 15 };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: mylatlongopt, title:co });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

I've read that this usually has something to do with using words that are reserved in IE but I've added z's and such to make the vars unique and still doesn't work..

What could this be?

Comment: Looking at the offending line, my guess would be that the google map files haven't loaded yet.  Are you sure that they have at that point?

Comment: I've got my Google Map script imported asynchronously at the top of the JS file. It works fine in FF, but how can I be sure that IE is loading the script properly?

Comment: If you made a codepen.io (or jsfiddle) it could be of great help to analyze; or past more code so that we can reproduce. As PugFugly implied, the .maps or the .LatLng cannot be invoked which may be caused by files not being loaded.

Comment: Matter of fact, I would get a "google is not defined" error if the script wasn't loaded, so yes, the files are importing properly.

Comment: I still think it's a problem with loading - Google maps appears to come through in a load of files.  So it could be that LatLng is defined in a file that hasn't yet loaded.  if I type `new google.maps.DoesntExist` into an IE console (when I know that Google Maps has fully loaded), I get the same error as you.  That suggests to me that Google Maps hasn't correctly fully loaded for some reason.

Comment: I am using the same thing in one of my apps right now with no issues, center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng). With that said, why don't you just set a break point on the code and walk through it to see what the values are and possibly step into functions, etc. Remember the debugger is available in the F12 tools. My guess is you have something else affecting the offending code and stepping through might help clear things up.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, "directions to home"..?

Comment: Directions to home is a link to directions, it has nothing to do with the map.